# Subdomains in Play 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, subdomain

Is it possible work with subdomains in Play 2.0 conf/routes? Like Play 1.1:

```
GET    {client}.mysoftware.com/         Application.index
```

How I can work with subdomains in my Play 2.0 app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The subdomain configuration is not done at the Play level, but at the reverse proxy level.

Comment: Thank you for answer. How long it will take(Play level)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.

Here's the definition of a route:

```
case class Route(verb: HttpVerb, path: PathPattern, call: HandlerCall) extends Positional
```

It accepts the verb (e.g. `GET`), the path component (i.e. not the domain or port, but only the path component) and the handler.

The definition of `PathPattern` can be found [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/router/Router.scala#L26), and as far as I can see, it doesn't cater for domain nor port.